# Equation of line passing through a point parallel to a given line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I have the point $(2,-5)$ and an equation $y-4 = 2x$ which is a straight line. I want to make another equation from the $(2,-5)$ that is parallel to $y-4 = 2x$ and you can only do this by making the gradients the same or if they are both vertical lines. So I thought the easiest way was to make $(2,-5)$ a vertical line but I wasn't quite sure how to form it.
I know that $x=k$ so would the vertical line equation in this case just be $x = 2$?

Comment: so i just need to rearrange to make it y=mx+c form and then make the slopes the same to make them parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To first define what the vertical line equation is, it the equation $x=k$, with $a$ being the x-intercept and $k$ being some number. The way the setup should be is by plugging in the intersecting point of $(2,-5)$ into the equation by plugging in the x-intercept into the vertical line equation, and you get out $2=k$. Hence that $x=k$, $x=2=k$. Which concludes that the final equation is $x=2$.

Comment: Im trying to make the two lines parallel and if what user137794 says is true and y-4=2x isn't a vertical line then don't I have to make (2,-5) in y=mc+c form? For this i got y=2x-9 for (2,-5) using the y-y1=m(x-x1) : y+5 = 2(x-2) -> y+5=2x-4 -> y=2x-9 and since they have the same slope they are parallel?

Comment: Yes. By the congruence laws, slope is the "slant" of the line. which shows that if the lines have different slopes," the lines will not be parallel. Hence that if you have a line any where on a coordinate plane parallel to another line, it is stated that both lines have the same slope.

Comment: Am i aloud to use the slope from y-4=2x (m=2) to form the other equation for (2,-5) ?

Comment: Yes you can. Hence that if you want to make both lines parallel.